# can we .find 2 classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve this:

```
var $optionSets = $('#options').find('.option-set','#talents')..
```

That doens't work.

basically i want to say to assign `var $optionSets` for both `.option-set` and `#talents`

Comment: the second is not a `class`, but an `id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve [multiple selections](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in one "query", seperate your selectors by a comma:

```
$('#options').find('.option-set, #talents')
```

Note: "#talents" is an ID selector, not a class selector

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/CfEqc/)**